# In Jmeter how to clean up variables defined as part of JDBC PreProcessor

Tags: jmeter

As a part of the jmeter request, I have a JDBC Preprocessor that inserts data and post that returns data which we are using to pass in the request body. Each Request inserts data and executes based on the said input.
I am facing an issue where in multiple requests fail as the same variables are used across.
How do I clean up the variable or make the variables local to the request?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just remove User Defined Variables everywhere, as per [documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables):

> The User Defined Variables element lets you define an **initial** set of variables, just as in the Test Plan.
>
> Note that all the UDV elements in a test plan - no matter where they are - **are processed at the start**.

So you don't need to "declare" a JMeter Variable, JDBC test element will **create** the variable which will be [local to the thread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage) (virtual user) so there shouldn't be duplicates while the values which you define in the User Defined Variables are **global** and used by all threads.

More information: [Using User Defined Variables](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421395-Using-User-Defined-Variables)

Comment: I have not defined as UserDefined Variables. These are part of the PreProcessor